/profile at the end of my URL causing web-scraping function to not work
I am trying to scrape data from Yahoo finance as part of a function. The URL with "/profile" at the end does not work, but if I take it off, the URL will pull in. Does anyone have any idea why that would be? Here is my code. Not sure why the "/profile" would break the URL but, its required as I want to pull more data on this website and its only on the profile pages.
def get_name(ticker):
    import requests, re
    
    # put the URL here
    url =f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/profile'
    
    # download
    req = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent': ua})
    html = req.text
    
    try:
        # use a regular expression to find the name
        name = re.search(r'(?<=<title>)(.*?)(?=\s\([A-Z]{3,4}\))', html)
        print(name)

    except:
        # if the regular expression fails, do nothing
        pass

I have tried pulling of the /profile which works, its just not the right link. I have also tried changing {ticker} to '+ticker+'

What does "does not work" mean?

It wont pull from that URL and gives a link that ends in no script. I have gone to the source page and know the source data and that this regex should work on it.

The page returned by view-source:https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/profile seems to have a <title>Microsoft Corporation (MSFT) Company Profile &amp; Facts - Yahoo Finance</title>

why would mine be returning this? (it goes on longer than this). I get this when I have the text its pulling printed vs going through the rest of the function. 
That JavaScript is designed to prevent people from embeddingYahoo Finance in iframes.

There are a number of APIs for getting financial information, why do it with web scraping?

It is for a class and I  have to use python to web-scrape. I even tried a classmate's code that worked for them and it wasn't working for me. I have figured out its something with the /profile at the end of the URL, but I don't know what to do about it.

It seems that I get that html returned if I call a url too often...
then it will return the "Content is currently unavailable" for 24 hours, and suddenly it's all working again.
